# Executing PHP file from command line with dynamic parameters

Tags: php, bash, shell

I need to run one script which will take one date as an argument. It is configured using cron to run on a daily basis, but I need to run it for a time range now. The issue is that this will fetch all results if it is ran for one day because of the huge size of the table. So is it possible to supply the each date from the start date dynamically from a shell script?

For example: if I need to run `update_cron.php` from `'2013-10-05'` then it needs to run

```
php update_cron.php '2013-10-05'
php update_cron.php '2013-10-06'
php update_cron.php '2013-10-07'
```

until today (or the end date which is specified). I am very new to shell scripting and so it will be helpful if someone can give an input to this.

Comment: Why does it take two arguments that are the same?

Comment: No. it can take one date also. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should get you started

```
iterdate() {
    cur="$1"
    end="$2"
    while [ $cur != $end ] 
    do
     echo php update_cron.php $cur 
     cur=$(date -d "$cur + 1 day"  +%Y-%m-%d)
    done
    }
```

The you can use it like this

```
$ iterdate 2013-10-05 2013-10-08
php update_cron.php 2013-10-05
php update_cron.php 2013-10-06
php update_cron.php 2013-10-07
```

Just remove the echo in it to make it actually run the `php update` command. Note that if you need to run that in a cron job, you might find it easier to make a script of it rather than a function. Then copy the following in a text file and make it executable

```
#!/bin/bash
cur="$1"
end="$2"
while [ $cur != $end ] 
do
  echo php update_cron.php $cur 
  cur=$(date -d "$cur + 1 day"  +%Y-%m-%d)
done
```

And then

```
$ /path/to/iterdate.sh 2013-10-05 2013-10-08
php update_cron.php 2013-10-05
php update_cron.php 2013-10-06
php update_cron.php 2013-10-07
```